# displaying output in html with a python code

Tags: python

I'm still learning the ins and outs of `python` and my goal right now is I want to display the outputs of my `python` code into a `html` webpage. How can I do that, provided that I already have a `html` webpage, but instead of the output displaying on the webpage itself, it displays on the `console` only.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
__author__ = 'kai'
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import urllib.parse
import requests

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    while True:
        orig = request.form['starting']
        if orig == "quit" or orig == "q":
            break
        dest = request.form['destination']
        if dest == "quit" or dest == "q":
            break
        url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({"key": key, "from": orig, "to":dest})
        print("URL: " +(url))
        json_data = requests.get(url).json()
        json_status = json_data["info"]["statuscode"]
        if json_status == 0:
            print("API Status: " + str(json_status) + " = A successful route call.\n")
            print("=============================================")
            print("Directions from " + (orig) + " to " + (dest))
            print("Trip Duration: " + (json_data["route"]["formattedTime"]))
            print("-----------------Distance in different units-----------------")
            print("Kilometers: " + str("{:.2f}".format((json_data["route"]["distance"])*1.61)))
            print("Miles: " + str(json_data["route"]["distance"]))
            print("Yards: " + str("{:.2f}".format((json_data["route"]["distance"])*1760)))
            print("-----------------Fuel Used in different units-----------------")
            print("Fuel Used (Ltr): " + str("{:.2f}".format((json_data["route"]["fuelUsed"])*3.78)))
            print("Fuel Used (US Gal): " + str(json_data["route"]["fuelUsed"]))
            print("Fuel Used (Imperial Gal): " + str("{:.2f}".format((json_data["route"]["fuelUsed"])*0.8327)))
            print("=============================================")
            for each in json_data["route"]["legs"][0]["maneuvers"]:
                print((each["narrative"]) + " (" + str("{:.2f}".format((each["distance"])*1.61) + " km)"))
                print("=============================================\n")
        elif json_status == 402:
            print("**********************************************")
            print("Status Code: " + str(json_status) + "; Invalid user inputs for one or both locations.")
            print("**********************************************\n")
        elif json_status == 611:
            print("**********************************************")
            print("Status Code: " + str(json_status) + "; Missing an entry for one or both locations.")
            print("**********************************************\n")
        else:
            print("************************************************************************")
            print("Try Again")
            print("************************************************************************\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3000)
```

Comment: Check how to use templates on flask. Documentation here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/templates/ and a nice tutorial here https://pythonbasics.org/flask-tutorial-templates/

Comment: Your program looks like a flask web app, but it prints to the console
and invokes requests on a different service (`main_api` - not defined here).
It's mixing a few different metaphors.  It's not clear what you think it's supposed to do.